# An Error On the Served GUID shoudl contain 32... Post Request to retrieve Image not showing in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, http-post, power-automate, powerapps, guid

I have the following Flow that Retrieves chemical Images dynamically from ChemSpider Depending on the SMILES entered. The steps for this flow generally are:

1. User inputs Text
2. Appends this to URL (Encoded)
3. send HTTP GET request to get the boxy of this page (Actually does this twice as there is a redirect)
4. create a file using the body of this request in a library called ImageTest/Images
5. Then send  HTTP post request to a column called Images within a list called QSAR Analysis SUbmission Data

I want these images to appear as part of a gallery viewable within my Canvas PowerApp however the retrieved image, despite being in the right column, within powerapps the image just appears blank.

[image]

I require a unique Id from the get file metadata step however I have so far been unable to achieve this. The metadata step in the flow is not yet utilised.

Header Body:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.QSAR_x0020_Analysis_x0020_DataListItem"
    },
    "Title": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}",
    "Image": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"id\":\"@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/ID']}\",\"fileName\":\"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}\",\"fieldName\":\"Image\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://rbcom.sharepoint.com\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/ReckittRfD/ImageTest/Images/@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}.png\"}"
}
```

Where xxx is specific.

Note the above code is **working** to post the found image but fails to display within powerapps.

initially, I got an error failed to retrieve information form the server error. After switching off Formula-level error management I get the following:

[image]